# Component Library - Managed Package Components

Tags: lightning, aura, documentation

It used to be that Managed Package global Aura components were viewable at `<org_url>/docs/component-library/overview/components`. Does anyone know what happened with this, or is anyone else also experiencing that Managed Package components are no longer documented by here?

In the past, all namespaces that had components were listed, and now I'm only seeing the `c` namespace (since our org is not namespaced), and the standard out-of-the-box SF namespaces.

This is frustrating, because we have our own managed package of reusable components, and it's nice to have built-in docs for them, so other devs know what's in the package and can see demos without having to look through the code.

Comment: I put some feelers out on Twitter for you, too. Hopefully we can get an answer for you.

Comment: This is a bug. 

We agree that its great to see your documentation in the Component Library for your managed packages. 

We'll be working to fix this soon.

Comment: Thanks guys, appreciate it

Comment: Is the same applicable to LWC?

Comment: LWC exposure is blocked by other work, its slowly making progress.

Comment: Update, we've identified the issue but its in the domain of another team. They've fixed it in the next release of salesforce, but haven't updated the current release. Its not a simple fix, so we're discussing the viability of patching the release vs waiting for the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed in the more recent seasonal releases.